# Is it possible to detect a transmitter that comes within a certan range?

Tags: wireless, rf, radio

I know nothing of electronics. My experience is with software engineering, not electronic engineering. This is a "Is it possible?" type question. If it isn't possible, where are the barriers?

I'm asking this in light of Friday's tragedy in Newtown, CT, which I'm sure we're all familiar with.

Naturally, this has invoked a renewed debate on gun control. But it seems to me that what we need is not more gun control -- people have the right to own guns.

What we need is a system that keeps guns out of certain public places, and this is a problem that only an automated system can effectively solve. We can't have airport-style security in every school and mall.

Here's what I'm thinking about.

I'm a student in college, and we are issued ID cards with a radio signature of some sort. We flash them in front of scanners to get into buildings on campus.

Is it not possible to build a comparable technology INTO GUNS? To require that all fire-arms sold and purchased in the United States are built with an embedded wireless-detectable signature?

Is it not possible to then place wireless detection systems around schools and malls which can detect if such a signature comes past a designated boundary, thus putting the area on lockdown and automatically summoning the police before the incident has even begun?

And the firearms belonging to police and current military would of course not set these systems off; their signatures would match "SAFE".

Then the only task left to the government is enforcing this manufacturing requirement (a much more tractable problem) and cracking down on aftermarket modifications.

Is my proposition unreasonable? It seems so obvious that I'm sure there must be a reason it hasn't already been done.

If it is possible, and nobody else wants to try it, can you point me in the direction of the topics I should educate myself on to better understand how such a technology would work?

**EDIT:**

In response to the first answer:

I do realize that a non-powered component would require close proximity. But I do not believe it would be a difficult task to move this technology forward to the stage where it does *not* require close proximity. If they can build a particle collider -- if they can get to the moon -- if they can build an iPhone -- if they can do all the incredible things you hear about *them* doing every day -- they can develop a method to detect a radio signature at a distance of 500 feet. Absolutely. This is not science fiction.

As for removing/destroying the component: Say this component took the form of a micro-chip embedded into the metal. Now say, for a given model of a gun, there are five locations on the gun where it could fit.

Say 100 instances of this model are manufactured. For 20 of them place the chip in location A. For the next 20, location B, and so on. This would require a change in the manufacturing process, but not an unreasonable one, nor a prohibitively costly one.

Then mix the 5 subtypes and sell them in homogeneous batches -- a person wouldn't know where the component was on their particular gun. They would have to cut through the gun in myriad places to find the component they seek to destroy. They would destroy the gun in so doing. It would be borderline impossible.

As for sniffing -- a person would need to understand what the detection system was looking for in a signature, exactly what information would NOT set off the system. If the internal information scheme was kept secret, this is not a concern.

As for getting innocents in trouble-- a person would have to know what sort of signature the detection system was looking for, what kind of information it would convey. Easily kept secret. The people with the ability to break such a system would rarely overlap with the people looking to commit murder.

However, I have yet to think of a way around the Faraday cage.

Comment: This is not a good fit for our site @aerovistae. I know such a solution would be nice, but brainstorming on how to track guns is off topic here and as answers also show it is not a good fit. Acting on the basis, "if we can build a particle collider," this is just open-ended brain-storming and wishing.

Comment: Yes, I understand; I got caught up in wishful thinking. The whole thing on Friday was rather upsetting.

Comment: you are not alone. :*(

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible, but, in my opinion, not practical. There a few issues with this approach. The first obvious one is that anyone wanting to commit a crime will simply remove or destroy this component.

Otherwise, the card you used only works at very close proximity. In order to make it work in a mall or whatever, it would need to be actively transmitting meaning it would need some sort of power source (battery) and antenna to transmit around saying it's active.

Bypassing that is again very easy: don't change the battery or remove it and it won't transmit. Then gun manufacturers need to build in special parts to house this electronics and battery/antenna too. 
Another way around is to wrap the gun in aluminium foil to act as a Faraday cage and again it won't transmit.

Someone could also make a DIY transmitter of this gun one and stick it in the purse or car of innocent non-gun-carrying people and get them in trouble over nothing.

An attacker could also sniff the signature of a "safe" law-enforcement gun and put it into their own.

For all these reasons, I do not think components inside the gun is a good detection approach.

If you want to go ahead with this anyway and try it, this project is a good starting point: http://www.openbeacon.org/ it is an open source active RFID badge and detectors for them.

Comment: See my edit regarding these barriers.

Comment: A chip in metal is then Faraday-caged on its own if it's inside metal...

As for not being cost-prohibitive to manufacturing, I'm not sure how you can say that. Choosing some locations, compromising integrity of the gun's structure, etc seem like huge and expensive problems.

Comment: I do realize how that sounds, but this is exactly the problem. You're looking for reasons it can't work instead of thinking of ways it can. I'm just one person with very little knowledge. If a team of very experienced and innovative engineers tried to design a gun with such a thing embedded, don't you think that there must be a way around that? Neither of these two "problems" are oh-God-this-project-can-never-succeed type barriers. This isn't a space elevator. It's just a change to an existing manufacturing process.

Comment: Great link, btw.

Comment: Besides, there must be a way to transmit through aluminum foil. There just has to be. It can't be that simple. No known signal can penetrate a simple wall of foil? Nothing? If I challenged MIT's engineering department to send a signal through a sheet of aluminum foil, they would waste years before giving up? I just don't believe that this can't be done.

Comment: When it's a forced change applying to hundreds of manufacturers world-wide, it might as well be a space elevator IMO.

And how do you deal with all the existing guns (100% right now) that don't have this? Who will pay to retrofit them all?  You also have to acknowledge that there is no way all the current ones will be retro-fitted for this and criminals will simply use those when committing crimes.

This isn't a technological so much as industrial challenge. I don't see what our ability to get on the moon has to do with successful implementation of this scheme.

Comment: The moon was just an example of us getting something done when we really put our minds to it, and this is something we should really be putting our minds to. I do acknowledge that barrier, but again, it is not intractable. WE would pay, with taxes, because this is important. If old-style guns were banned and collected (in exchange for new-style guns), it would only be a matter of time before such guns were very difficult to come by. Especially since the government keeps track of who owns guns in the first place.

Comment: You should perhaps read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

if you and whoever you think at MIT can defeat this physics phenomenon, you'll be rich and famous not just for putting chips in guns.

Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm sorry. I just want to believe it can be done somehow. If such a scheme existed, it would end this kind of violence without compromising second amendment rights. I just feel like it must be possible somehow.

Comment: Aluminum is non-magnetic so magnetic fields eg 30 to 300KHz can be used to transmit thru foil.. Unfortunately for every technical fix there is a hack to work around it,.

Comment: @Aerovistae foil will not block all signals, as richman says magnetic fields can go through, which really means a near field magnetic coupling can, which is what RFID is, but it is still not easy to have it couple through.